# Action cost to get smooth path

Tags: motion-planning

What action cost should be used to get a smooth path? Like we use distance traversed to get the shortest path. Will the cost to get a smooth path will be something related to rate of change of slope of the path?

Comment: Can you define smooth? I think what you're looking for is minimizing jerk, where jerk is the third derivative of position (first derivative of acceleration).

Comment: By smooth I mean path free of any spikes or corners.

Comment: as Chuck said, minimize for jerk. Also you might want to take a look at jerk minimal trajectory planning.